How can I sort the result based on the order specified?
I have a query that uses a comma-separated string as input. I want to sort the result based on the order of the IDs in the comma-separated string.
Declare @IDList varchar(100) = '4,2,5,1';  -- Result should appear in this order

Select ID, Value From MyTable Where ID In (Select Item From dbo.Split(@IDList,','))

dbo.Split function returns a table with column Item.
ID is the primary identity key in the table MyTable.
Currently, the result appears in the order of ID: 1, 2, 4, 5. I want to sort it based on the IDs specified in the string: 4, 2, 5, 1. Can that be done?

@MartinSmith 2019

Add a row_counter column to the Split function and you're good to go. You can also use some xml or json tricks to split string another way, there's probably a gazillion of string split functions written on SO alone

Easiest way of getting the ordinal in a guaranteed way on 2019 would probably be to pass the string as '[4,2,5,1]' then use something like SELECT value FROM OPENJSON('[4,2,5,1]') ORDER BY CAST([key] AS INT)

Had never heard of OPENJSON. Will check it out.

Be warned though that Entity Framework use(d) this sort of approach and had a ton of complaints about performance where the execution plan is sensitive to either number of values in the list or their specific values - as it can't get good estimates of these when hidden in opaque strings

Pretty strong rule of them: if you care about the order, you MUST have an ORDER BY clause somewhere to enforce it. But you're not ordering by the IDs in your list. You're ordering by the index of the IDs in your list. And that info isn't provided as part of the Split() function. You'll need to add a row_number() projection or similar to do it.

For SQL Server 2016+, you can use an ordered split function, like this one using OPENJSON():
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitString_WithOrdinal
(
  @List  varchar(max), 
  @Delim varchar(10)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    SELECT value, 
           ordinal = [key] + 1
      FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[',
           REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(@List, 'JSON'), 
           @Delim, ','), ']')) AS j
  );

Then your query is:
DECLARE @IDList varchar(100) = '4,2,5,1';

SELECT mt.ID, f.value, f.ordinal
  FROM dbo.MyTable AS mt
 INNER JOIN dbo.SplitString_WithOrdinal(@IDList, ',') AS f
    ON f.value = mt.ID
 ORDER BY f.ordinal;

If JSON isn't your thing, or you're on a version older than 2016 (yikes), you could do this (adapted from this answer), as long as the length of the string representing your list could never be longer than the number of rows in sys.all_columns (over 12K in modern versions):
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.SplitString_WithOrdinal
(
  @List  varchar(max),
  @Delim varchar(10)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN 
  ( 
    SELECT value, 
           ordinal = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o)
    FROM 
    ( 
      SELECT value = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, o,
        CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, o) - o))), o
      FROM (SELECT o = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
        FROM sys.all_columns) AS x WHERE o <= LEN(@List)
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, o, LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
    ) AS y
  );

If your string can be longer than that, well, there are other solutions, like this one.

db<>fiddle


For SQL Server 2022 (and in Azure SQL Database / MI), you will be able to just replace...
dbo.SplitString_WithOrdinal(@IDList, ',') AS f 

...with...
STRING_SPLIT(@IDList, ',' 1) AS f

So, you wouldn't need a function at all, and your query would just be:
DECLARE @IDList varchar(100) = '4,2,5,1';

SELECT mt.ID, f.value, f.ordinal
  FROM dbo.MyTable AS mt
 INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@IDList, ',', 1) AS f
    ON f.value = mt.ID
 ORDER BY f.ordinal;

These are all demonstrated in the above db<>fiddle.

Use CHARINDEX to get the position in the string. Only make sure to include the commas, so as to avoid detecting a 4 in '4444,44,444'. This means in above example you'll look for ',4,' in ',4444,44,444,'.
In order to deal with IDs not in the list, which I assume must be put at the end of the list, we must turn the zero returned by CHARINDEX into some high number. I am using a combination of NULLIF and COALESCE for this.
ORDER BY 
  COALESCE(
    NULLIF(
      CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',', 
                ',' + @IDList + ',')
    , 0)
  , 9999999999)

The good thing about this: There is no trick used. About every database developer knows these functions, and all that is needed to get the desired order is placed directly in the ORDER BY clause.
If the result is guaranteed to only have IDs that are in the comma-delimited string, as in your query, the ORDER BY reduces to
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',', 
                   ',' + @IDList + ',')

of course.
https://dbfiddle.uk/Z3Gm7DsX

I am assuming that numbers in IdList can be bigger than 4. Here is what you can do
DECLARE @IDList VARCHAR(100) = '4,2,5,1';

WITH OrderedIDs AS (
    SELECT 
        Item AS ID, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS OrderPos
    FROM dbo.Split(@IDList, ',')
)
SELECT 
    MyTable.ID, 
    MyTable.Value
FROM MyTable
JOIN OrderedIDs ON MyTable.ID = OrderedIDs.ID
ORDER BY OrderedIDs.OrderPos;

Explaination:

Split the numbers from IdList
ROW_NUMBER() =>  This assigns a sequential number to each ID based on the order they appear in the @IDList.
we then join the result of the Split function using the row_numbers and order the results


"based on the order they appear in the @IDList" is not at all documented as guaranteed

Yes, @IDList can have many numbers. This might work. Will test and see.

ORDER BY SELECT NULL definitely does not guarantee it will assign in sequential order. Where is this documented?

Agree, depending on an undocumented behavior like this is a bad idea. There are other techniques out there that work using guaranteed behavior.
